# What is use of fields in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a `type` parameter which its value text, and again under the `fields` there is another `type` parameter which its value text. I don't understand what `english` and `another` are meaning. Can you tell me what is `fields` parameter's functionality and how can we use or benefit from them simply?

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "text": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "english": { 
              "type":     "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "another": {
              "type":     "keyword",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This structure is called a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields).

The idea behind that is to be able to apply a different analysis pipeline to each sub-fields. In your case, the `text.english` sub-field will be analyzed using the [`english` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) and the `text.another` sub-field will be analyzed by the [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).

The beauty of it is that your document only needs to have a `text` field and then in your queries you'll be able to reference the `text`, `text.english` and `text.another` sub-fields transparently.

```
# Your document
{
    "text": "The nice dog runs after the cat"
}
```

After indexing this document,

- in your `text.english` sub-field you're going to have the following tokens: `nice`, `dog`, `run`, `after`, `cat`
- in your `text.another` sub-field you're going to have the following tokens: `the`, `nice`, `dog`, `runs`, `after`, `the`, `cat`
- finally in your top-level `text` field you're going to have the same tokens as in `text.another` because the `standard` analyzer is also the default one when no analyzer is specified on a text field.

Comment: I know analyzers but we define them in settings > analysis > analyzer > my_analyzer. Are they different ways to define analyzers? Also my text field's type is text, but in the another its type is keyword. So as far as I understand, I can specify different type parameter for different analyzers, is it right?

Comment: In settings you can define [custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html), i.e. ones that you customize to your own needs. In your mappings, you can then use built-in analyzers (like `english` and `standard` in your case, as well as the custom ones you've defined in your settings. The `keyword` fields do not undergo any analysis process, the content of those fields is stored as is in a single token.

Comment: On keyword fields you can use so-called [normalizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) with which you can apply a few transformations to your non-analyzed fields (lowercase, etc)

Comment: So we aren't define them(analyzers) in fields, we are just using them. But I don't understand how can text property has text type and in "another" has keyword type in the same time? Is it for indexing both ways: indexing token by token and indexing as a whole value?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you provide the data only once and it gets indexed in two different sub-fields in two different ways.